Is there a classification of 2D projective convolution kernels?
Is there any classification of all distributions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that they are equal to the convolution with themselves? i.e. given a distribution $\gamma$ under which conditions
$$ \gamma\star\gamma=\gamma.$$
